# ¿Tiene la palabra "sanata" uso fuera del español rioplatense?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, dialectos, argentina, uruguay

Según un sitio en internet, "sanata" es una palabra de origen argentino que se usa en Argentina y Uruguay (dialecto español rioplatense). ¿Tiene esta palabra uso fuera de estos países? ¿Puedes utilizarla con habitantes de otros países hispanos y que estos te entiendan?

Comment: Alguna información adicional podría ser útil. ¿Que quiere decir ese vocablo? ¿Dónde lo has visto? ¿En qué contexto? ¿Has probado a buscar algo en algún sitio? Recuerda que en español hay que escribir el símbolo **"¿"** en las oraciones interrogativas (parece faltar en 3 de las 4 frases que forman tu pregunta. Puedes mejorar la pregunta cliqueando en **"edit"**

Comment: ¿Te refieres a https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanata ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para estos casos te recomiendo que uses el *Diccionario de americanismos*, accesible desde las webs de [la RAE](http://www.rae.es/) y [la ASALE](http://www.asale.org/), seleccionando en el desplegable del tipo de diccionario el denominado así.

> [**sanata**](http://    ).
>       I.  1.  f. *Ar; Ur*, p.u.
>   Conversación, discurso o explicación larga y pesada. pop + cult →
>   espon.
>          2.    *Ar*. Embuste,
>   mentira. pop + cult → espon.

Las marcas *Ar, Ur* indican que solo se usa en Argentina y Uruguay. De hecho, en la [entrada de la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanata) enlazada [por Leonardo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/26434/tiene-la-palabra-sanata-uso-fuera-del-espa%C3%B1ol-rioplatense#comment43858_26434) se indica que la palabra es típica del lunfardo, confirmando su uso solo en esa zona.

Por la primera acepción registrada, palabras similares pueden ser *[reláfica](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Vock8Zx)* (usada en Venezuela) y *[rollo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WdApXKx)* (usada en España, ver acepción 13).

Comment: También la más onomatopéyica *sarasa* (no en [la acepción que tiene el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XHxrjAe), obviamente).